Ejecutar UPDATE en SQLite mediante Python
tengo el siguiente inconveniente en python usando tkinter, tengo una ventana de actualización que me lee los datos de la base de datos correctamente, y me permite editar siempre y cuando no se elimine un registro, cada vez que se elimina un registro de la base de datos y la columna id queda desfasada(sin un valor correlativo) no me permite actualizar mas, python me indica que todo esta correcto, pero el cambio en la base de datos no se ve reflejada.
Alguien podria explicarme como funciona?
Gracias de antemano.

Necesito ver tu código para poder responderte pero por lo que entiendo se te desfasa el id de la base de datos, deduzco que tienes un auto_increment en el id de la base de datos, lo que pasa con eso es que al eliminar un registro el id que ocupaba ese registro no se ocupa por uno nuevo entonces por ejemplo tienes los id 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 si agregas otro elemento a la base de datos tendrás 1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6 y si ahora eliminas el 6 y vuelves a agregar otro registro a la base de datos esta quedara con los id 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7 lo que puedes hacer es a la tabla agregar un campo nuevo que indique si el elemento esta activo o no y así no lo elimines solo cambias el estado de ese campo porque por regla general no esta recomendado eliminarlos lo otro que puedes hacer es tener otra tabla duplicada y que en una se eliminen y en la otra no y haces la comparación de si el elemento esta en las las dos tablas ahí se muestre, de todas formas si necesitas mas ayuda o mi respuesta no te ayudo lo mejor seria que dejes tu código para ver que esta pasando.

Muchas gracias por la respuesta, era un inconveniente con Tkinter, cada vez que intentaba actualizar habia un desfasaje con los indices, logre corregir eso y reacomode los datos de las columnas, quedo funcionando.
